# React - Are Class based Components fully supported in React?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-components

React - Are Class based Components fully supported in React
Or there is limited support for Class based Components in React ?

I want to implement  Class based Object Oriented Design approach in React.
But, I am not sure whether the Class based Components and Object Oriented Design Approach is fully supported in react or not (including support for hooks, states and all other functionalities)?

Comment: Many libraries changed their API to hooks. Also, it was never a truly OOP approach event with class components

Comment: Is it better idea to use Typescript with React if React does not recommend Class based Component approach ?

Comment: See if this article helps. https://react.dev/blog/2023/03/16/introducing-react-dev#going-all-in-on-modern-react-with-hooks

Comment: @SantoshDumbre React is a JavaScript library, TypeScript generates JavaScript. If you choose to use TypeScript, you can use the TypeScript types provided by React to enable type checking in your editor. Writing an OOP or non-OOP program doesn't change any of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component):

> Component is the base class for the React components defined as
> JavaScript classes. **Class components are still supported by React, but
> we don’t recommend using them in new code**.

It is also stated there that it is recommended to migrate your class components to functions.

[Reference](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#migrating-a-simple-component-from-a-class-to-a-function)

Comment: If Class based Components are not recommended in latest versions of React, does it recommend to use Typescript with react as Typescript fully support Class and Object Oriented Design?

Comment: Any idea from which version of React this recommendation regarding function components instead of class components comes in effect ?

Comment: @SantoshDumbre - React has no recommendation whatsoever regarding Typescript. It does have a section explaining how you can use Typescript ([reference](https://react.dev/learn/typescript)). Regarding your second question, that is not documented, but you can see that the link I shared above is under a section titled **Legacy React APIs**. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: Why is this recommendation made? Why do the React team suggest NOT using class type components? What is the reason for it?